# Redrawing children sprites with scaling the scene?

Tags: parent-child, sprite-kit, scaling, children

Spritekit

I have a world map as a level background. I am placing ShapeNodes (dots) and LabelNodes as children to the world sprite to mark major cities throughout the world. All looks good.

When I scale the world sprite to specific countries, the dots and labels scale as you would expect and maintain their position within the world. The dots and labels become pixelated and don't look very good.  What's the best way to handle this? I need the children to maintain their position at all times, but "redraw" or stay at the same scale regardless of the world scale.

Not sure how to approach this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: showing the zoom method

```
static const int MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT = 6;
static const CGFloat SCALE_AMOUNT = 1.5;
static const CGFloat ANIMATION_DURATION = .15;
- (void)zoomWorld:(BOOL)zoomIn fromLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation {

    CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    CGPoint mySkNodeShift = CGPointSubtract(anchorPoint, CGPointMultiplyScalar(anchorPoint, SCALE_AMOUNT));
    SKAction *scaleUp = [SKAction group:@[
                                        [SKAction scaleBy:SCALE_AMOUNT duration:ANIMATION_DURATION],
                                        [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(mySkNodeShift.x, mySkNodeShift.y) duration:ANIMATION_DURATION]
                                        ]];
    SKAction *scaleDown = [scaleUp reversedAction];

    if (zoomIn) {
        if (self.zoomLevel < MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT) {
            [self.world runAction:scaleUp];
            self.zoomLevel++;
        }
    } else if (!zoomIn) {
        if (self.zoomLevel > 0) {
            [self.world runAction:scaleDown];
            self.zoomLevel--;
        }
    }
    self.world.position = [self boundLayerPos:self.world.position];

    //Reset UI after the zoom
    if (self.zoomLevel > 2) [self toggleCityLabels:YES];
    else if (self.zoomLevel < 3) [self toggleCityLabels:NO];

    if (self.zoomLevel < 0) self.zoomLevel = 0;
    else if (self.zoomLevel > MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT) self.zoomLevel = MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT;
}


-(void)toggleCityLabels:(BOOL)on {
    if (on) {
        for (AMCity *city in self.arrayOfCities) {
            [self.world addChild:city.citySprite];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (AMCity *city in self.arrayOfCities) {
            [city.citySprite removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the image quality, I would suggest having different textures for different scaling levels. For example, use texture1 for a scale between 1.0 to 0.8. Use texture2 for 0.8 to 0.6. And so on...

As for the labels you can use the same logic. Figure out which dots/labels are currently in view and create new labels to fit the scale factor. This is assuming you have all your nodes stored in an array.

Comment: Yes all nodes are in an array. I'm not using any images or textures. I'm using ShapeNodes and LabelNodes which are drawn for me. I've attempted removing and re-adding the dots (Shapenodes) and Labelnodes at different zoom levels. They are just as pixelated as if I just left them there while scaling.

Comment: How much of a zoom are we talking about here?

Comment: Edited my post to show zoom method. The world.png being used for the world sprite is 6310x3353 and is scaled to fit during init. Then, each zoom scales it up or down 1.5.

Comment: And added my toggleCities method to show how I am removing and adding the sprites at higher scale levels. I'm simply removing from parent, and re-adding when needed. When re-adding, it shows up just the same. I expected it to be a normal scale.

Comment: I've been trying a couple of different angles on this but I cannot come up with a solution to fit your code. Any way you slice this you will get bad resolution past a certain scale. I tried substituting same PNG but with different resolutions but no joy. I realize if you don't parent/child them you will lose your exact positional relationship but I don't see any way to fix this using your current code logic. I think you either limit the zoom and/or have various whole screen sprites for data on country/city selection. What do you think?

Comment: I considered marking the cities/dots directly on the world.png to eliminate one issue. I would still need dynamic labels to move around depending on map panning, etc. I think if you scale a node, and THEN add a child to it, the child should not be automatically scaled. It should let me decide if I choose for them to scale independent of their parent. Wishful thinking.

Comment: I agree 100%. I think the best course you can take now is to rethink your game flow. Have a world map on "Layer 1". Player then taps on a country/city. Overlay a new full size screen sprite showing the selection (layer 2) and so on. To get back to previous layers you only need to remove current sprite (layer) from parent. That's my 5 cents. Tell me if you want me to delete my answer so other people don't think your question has been answered.

Comment: That's ok. I haven't marked it as an accepted answer so we'll see if someone else has any input. I really appreciate you taking the time to try to help. I'm going to tinker with this for a bit.

Comment: Good luck. +1 for having a great question!

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about this?   Take Atlanta, for example. It's position within the world coordinate system is (255, 356). Is there a way to translate what that position equates to in the sibling node? I don't think convert point would work, would it? Maybe something like.... city.citySprite.position = CGPointMake(city.positionOnMap.x + (SCALE_AMOUNT * MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT), city.positionOnMap.y +(SCALE_AMOUNT * MAX_ZOOM_AMOUNT));   (that doesn't work, but if I come up with the right formula.. think it would work?)

Comment: If you can figure out the right formula, then that should work.

Comment: @JustinDamnMoore - I ran across this today. It might be what you are looking for. Converting coordinates from one node to another. convertPoint:fromNode:  it's in the SKNode class library.

Comment: I mentioned convert point in my last comment. I did find another solution to what I wanted. I will post details soon. Thanks for looking though.